# Solving N Equation with N variable Parametric in Matlab based on one of the variables

Tags: matlab, equation

I am new in Matlab, 
I Have 3 equation like this:

-5*x + y + z == 0;

x - 2*y + z == 0;

x + y - z == 0;

I want to have the value of y and z based on x
for example

z= 3*x

y= 2*x

can any one help me?

(if 'solve' (matlab command) can be used, please explain how?)one

Comment: Isn't it a standard homogeneous, linear system?

Comment: and isn't the triplet `[0,0,0]` the answer to this question?

Comment: you know, indeed i want to solve sth like: (a+x)(b+y)(c+z)=d, which a,b,c,d are constants. i want to find the value of y and z based on x to subsitute, and find x, so then y and z. there is a relation between x, y and z which create those 3 equation and that's why i need to solve them parameticly

Comment: of course i don't need [0,0,0]

Comment: so sorry, i am new to Stackoverflow too :( i see in my inbox one answer to my question, but i can't see the answer .... what should i do? :( so sorry

Comment: I tried to input a possible solution, but it is not the resolutive approach, thus I deleted it: that is why you cannot visualize it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible way to solve this question is by using the symbolic toolbox.

I would proceed as follows:

```
syms x y z real
assumptions(x)
assumptions(y)
assumptions(z)
f1 = '-5*x + y + z';
f2 = 'x - 2*y + z';
f3 = 'x + y - z';
Sol = solve(f1,f2,f3,'x,y,z');
Sol.x
Sol.y
Sol.z
```

The results are gonna be

```
Warning: The solutions are parametrized by the symbols:
u = R_

> In solve at 180 

ans =

u/3


ans =

(2*u)/3


ans =

u
```

This means that the triplet `(x,y,z)` will assume a different value depending on the value you assign to `u`, as for example

```
subs(Sol.x,1) = 0.3333
```

I hope this will clarify any doubt you may have.

Comment: if my answer is fulfilling your expectation, you could think about accepting it.

Comment: i've accepted it. Do i have to do sth else? or close the question? if yes, how?